# Why does Visual Studio Code continue to indent after a }?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, indentation

i got a strange issue,
i frequently have to used the auto indent on VS but when i'm in php, it seems to act strange when i'm coding classes, (thats really annoying cause im at 8 indent now at the start of a class[enter image description here])
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3C8S.png)

i'm explaining :

normal indent :

```
class 1{
   setting
   setting
   function(){
      setting
   }
}
class 2{
   setting
...
}
```

what i am having:

```
class 1{
   setting
   }
   class 2
      setting
      }
      class 3{
         setting
        }
```

Comment: What's your VS Code version? I'm not seeing this in 1.84.2 (I retyped the code from your screenshot). Are you seeing the same behaviour with nested `if` / `foreach` and / or functions?

Comment: no it only does that with the class, im in 1.87.2

Comment: what PHP extensions do you have installed, and what are their version numbers? is the code you're showing the only content in the file?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode